# Settings Menu missing Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, menu, settings, new-operator, ubuntu-22.04

So I was trying to get back the menu settings that dissapear after ubutu made the upgrade  to 22.04 version.

Honestly I'm new in all this.
This is the code that I'm getting:

I try:

root@blast-ThinkPad-T430:/home/blast# apt-get install gnome-control-center

I get:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/bin/python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/usr'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python310.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10',
    '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the file
system encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00007f4376fc2740 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
```

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Thanks in advance.

Try to get back my settings menu and logo.

Answer (score 30):

does your python-error disappear when using

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

instead of su / change user to root and leaving the sudo? Changing to root comes with more than just root privileges. You will use e.g. your user environment variables.

btw is this "missing settings UI" a weird thinkpad-bug? I know about this only from thinkpad users :O

Comment: Not only on thinkpad, I have a different laptop and after the last update I got the same problem

Answer (score 18):

This issue is mostly related to issues with the Gnome Control Center.
Reinstall it by running this command:

```bash
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

Comment: For me Settings disappeared following an Ubuntu 22 update, which is troubling. Your cli incantation worked a charm after a reboot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error message when trying to install the gnome control panel on a new system.  Currently no network card was picked up nor was the control panel.

> Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process
> 17520 (unattended-upgr) N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not
> a solution and may break your system. E: Unable to acquire the dpkg
> frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using
> it?

Answer (score 0):

“Unity-control-center” is a graphical user interface to configure various aspects of Unity. You just need to uninstall and reinstall unity-control-center it will fix this problem.

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```

Then:

```
sudo reboot
```